# Mask not being applied to input with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" id="cpfcnpj" ng-model="PersonalIdentificationNumber" ui-mask-placeholder="" ui-mask="000.000.000-00" name="PersonalIdentificationNumber" model-view-value="true" required="" readonly="" class="ng-pristine ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched">
```

But when I receive data to fill the input and apply that same data to the ng-model:

```
$scope.PersonalIdentificationNumber = result.Result.PersonalIdentificationNumber;
```

The mask is not being properly formatted. Instead of `000.000.000-00` I get `00000000000`.

Already tried this solution and also with: `$("#cpfcnpj").attr('mask', '000.000.000-00');` But none of them works.

Comment: can you please post demo in fiddle/plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set mask as: `ui-mask="999.999.999-99"`

<kbd>[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37exx6fp/)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Heelo try to use this:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask)

Angular directly not provide ui-masking.

Comment: I am using it. That is why I am using ui-masking